# What's the meaning of "torn" or "torn from sleep"?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, word-meaning, sentence-meaning

It's in the book 'The Last Wish: Introducing the Witcher'
It happened after the character Geralt fights a fast and strong creature. He falls bleeding and wakes up, his neck injury attended by someone.

"Geralt?"
He raised his head, torn from sleep.

Comment: Do you mean that he is woken _by_ someone starting to treat his injury? If you are 'torn from sleep' you are roused by a sudden disturbance.

Comment: As far as I could understand, someone treated him, but someone else is calling his name.

Comment: Coming to think of it better, your answer fits perfectly, that you are roused by a sudden disturbance. Thank you, I could not find a hint in any dictionaryl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, it is clear from context that Geralt is the one who is being torn from sleep. Specifically, Geralt is still in the process of waking up reluctantly as if removed forcibly from (torn out of) the sleeping state that Geralt was previously in (due to neck trauma).

Despite some grammatical ambiguity, it is clearly not the case that Geralt feels torn about having slept. It is also not the case that Geralt's head or neck has been torn physically as a result of the sleep. The surrounding description of the scene describes a groggy Geralt who wakes up after sustaining a massive battle injury. Thus Geralt is torn away from the action of sleeping.

Comment: Wow. What an explanation! Thank you!